# Using the ONS JSON-stat Viewer on non-ONS JSON-stat responses

Tags: json, viewer, ons-api

The [JSON-stat viewer](https://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/apiservice/web/apiservice/jsonstat) won't work on non-ONS JSON-stat responses. The problem seems to be generated by the **fixGeocount** function. Couldn't the line

```
jsonstat2 = fixGeocount(jsonstat);
```

be removed (jsonstat2 is never used), or at least conditionally executed only when the output comes from ONS?

The ONS JSON-stat Viewer would gain in scope, as it could be used on ONS outputs and non-ONS outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that, we're going to move all the Example code over to GitHub in the next week or two so I'll make sure that fix goes in then, that should also make things easier to maintain and allow people to send pull requests :)

Our Github account is https://github.com/onsdigital

Rgds
Sam